# How to draw a graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

draw a graph of equation in the form of **y=mx+b** in python3.x
example **y = 5x + 9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your `y(x)` function and then plot it as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def y(x):
    return [5*i+9 for i in x]

x = range(0,10)
plt.plot(x,y(x))
plt.show()
```

This produces follwing graph:

[image]

**With turtle**

You can as well get a graph with turtle with following code for example:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def y(x):
    return 5*x+9

def plotter(turtle, x_range):
    turtle.penup()
    for x in x_range:
        turtle.goto(x, y(x))
        turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 9, 60)
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

x = range(0,10)
plotter(turtle, x)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Which produces:
[image]

Comment: and how about using a turtle and how can we do it in turtle? because i need to use setworldcoordinates.

Comment: Please update your question with what you could reach out (means code you wrote till now) and be more specific on what you need then.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question. Try to be more specific. It depends how you want to draw it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
y = 5 * x + 9
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

or

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-1., 5., 0.2)
y = 5 * x + 9
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.grid(True, which='both')
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
```

These are very basic drawing. You can create more sophisticated graphs, but you will have to be more specific in your question.

Comment: and how about using a turtle and how can we do it in turtle? because i need to use setworldcoordinates.

Comment: I think @Cedric Zoppolo wrote a good enough answer. If you are missing something let me know/

Comment: I have posted a question but no one is responding. It's part of my assignment whoever solves that for me I will give him/her an up vote please. it is related to turtle problem